# Selecting an objects child mesh in Python

Tags: python, mesh, scripting

An object can be selected using `obj.select_set(True)`.

How can I select this objects child (Mesh.004 in the image)?

[image]

I tried `obj.data.select_set(True)`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you want to select it? Just for a visual effect of it being selected in the outliner, or is there another reason?

Comment: I want to set a plugin-related variable (bpy.context.scene.collider_enum_items.gamemats), I've found that this only works when the mesh itself is selected.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to select items for code to work under the hood. Most likely you need an operator override somewhere in your script. Could you post a snippet of code of that feature ?

Comment: It turns out I got something wrong, it wasn't actually necessary to select the mesh, the object just needed to both be selected and the active object.